# What are the minimum items I need to get from the Overworld to the End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm planning to do a "speedrun" per say.  Not really a speedrun, but a run that invovles creating a new world in hardcore mode, and venturing to the End to defeat the Ender Dragon.

My question is this.  What are the minimum items I will need to reach the enderdragon? What items will I need? What food, what potions, what weapons will I need to bring? (Do I need anything higher than an Iron Pickaxe?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reach the enderdragon, you will need to be able to kill Endermen; you'll need their enderpearls. However you plan to do that, you'll want the weapons or potions you plan to use against them, that's very individual.

You'll also need to reach the Nether; this means you need obsidian. If you use the frame-building method, you can make do with just some buckets (3 iron per bucket), lava, and water. You then will need to be able to kill blazes; again, it depends on your preferred method. The safest way is probably to build bows and arrows and go at it with a potion of fire resist (once you kill the first one, you can brew these, having collected netherwort and more iron), but you'll might want to sacrifice safety for speed, so you might want to hold off on the potion aspect.

Ender pearl + blaze powder = eye of ender. Finding a stronghold can be done with the eyes, and once you've found one, you can easily get to the end. Killing the ender dragon, of course, is another story, you might want gear for that. Really, it all depends on your fighting style.

So in essence, it depends on your plan for killing the high-level mobs. You can get away with nothing more than iron tools, sure, so long as you're skilled enough with them.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the bare minimum amount of items needed, with a lot of luck involved, you just need 3 items.

1) Some **eyes of ender** to open the portal and

2) A **bow** with

3) (lots of) **Arrows** to shoot down the orbs on the towers in the End and to kill the dragon.

(*This is assuming you don't need to dig at all to find a stronghold to get to the portal room and not counting the items needed to get to the nether to find blaze powder.*)

Of course Pickaxes, swords, armor, food and potions are greatly beneficial for the dragon fight as well as getting the ender pearls and blaze powder to make the eyes of ender. As for the tier of weapons/tools, iron should suffice but diamond is always better.